# Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]' in my custom alloc method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, self

I init my custom view with my custom method :

1) In My View Controller I am calling custom view and pass this array to my custom class that is of type UIView

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewiPhoneLayout" owner:self options:nil];

customViewObject = [[CustomView alloc] initWithArray:array];

[ParentLayout addSubview:customViewObject];
```

2) Custom View.

```
 -(id)initWithArray:(NSArray*)array {
      self = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // passing view as self; here it shows leak.
      if(self) {}
      return self;
  }
```

It giving me possible leak named `Returning 'self' while it is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'`

Comment: I'm not sure your code makes any sense.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I am trying to do is that I passing the instant that is created in parent as a self so all the action will automatically call methods of custom class

Comment: for ex. If i click the button of subview that is dynamically added in parent it will call the related method of custom view class because it  has the reference of custom instant

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use a class in a role that is best suited for an instance.  Given that any class method can be implemented on an instance to do the exact same thing, why not just go with instances?

Comment: You realise that this object won't be a CustomView object, but whatever your loadNibNamed method returns as its first object?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you are using an `init` function without using one of the super functions.  Although it may make logical sense, it is technically misuse of the `init` function, and this is why the compiler is complaining.  This will not always be a problem (I had some code that only gave me a warning on it before I fixed it), but it is a good practice not to work that way.  In this case, this is not proper use of the init function.  I would write another function like this:

```
+(customViewObject *)createWithArray:(NSArray *)array{
     customViewObject *returnObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
     return returnObject;
}
```

However, looking at the first bit of code, I see no need to have a function of this sort in the customViewObject class.  I would recommend simply doing this:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewiPhoneLayout" owner:self options:nil];

customViewObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];

[ParentLayout addSubview:customViewObject];
```

Comment: The variable array is a parameter variable (and hence a local variable), it is not an instance variable. Though the method (not function, that is something different) doesn't make sense there is nothing wrong *per se* with the uses of array; and the error message is unrelated to array.

Comment: I misread the code about the instance variable thing; thank you.  I will go modify my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For sure you don't need this, as far as:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewiPhoneLayout" owner:self options:nil];

customViewObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

In your code you alloc a view and loose it assigning self.

Comment: Of course I read before I answer, still can't see why do you need this. You create CustomView while you load a nib, then you alloc another CustomView, throw it away and return first one. That's what I see.

Comment: no @Maniak. object is the same i am passing the view for the object because there are two different .xib file for iPad and iPhone

Comment: @BaZinga: no matter what you may think, MANIAK_dobrii's code does the EXACT same thing as yours, minus a wasted allocation

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i fix it by remove these code

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewiPhoneLayout" owner:self options:nil];
customViewObject = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

from the definition init method.

use above code at the place where you create the custom view rather than in custom's definition body.